# window.alert not working when a form quiz is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, popup

So, I am trying to make a quiz with html/js. I searched up how to reference an ID from js but even then the js function isn't working when I click the D option and submit.

Basically, I'm trying to get a window alert once someone has pressed submit on an answer option.

[What the code outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKIHZ.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="missingletter.css">
    <title>Missing letter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="images"></div>
    <div class="wordToGuess"></div>
    <form action="">
        <p class="question">What is the missing letter?</p>
        <!-- image of cat -->
        <p class="cat">_ A T</p>
        <input type="radio" id="c" name="cat" value="cat">
        <label for="cat" class="answer options">C</label><br><br>

        <input type="radio" id="m" name="mat" value="mat">
        <label for="cat" class="answer options">M</label><br> <br>

        <input type="radio" id="d" name="dat" value="dat">
        <label for="cat" class="answer options">D</label><br> <br>

        <input type="submit" value="submit">


    </form>

    <script>
        if ($('radio').attr("d") == "submit") {
            window.alert("Correct")
        } else {
            window.alert("try again")
        }
    </script>
    <div class="letters"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must add a submit listener to the form. From there, you can check if the value is correct to show the correct alert. When using radio button, use the same `name` attribute to group them.

```html
<form id="myForm" action="">
  <p class="question">What is the missing letter?</p>
  <!-- image of cat -->
  <p class="cat">_ A T</p>
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="cat">
  <label for="cat" class="answer options">C</label><br><br>

  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="mat">
  <label for="cat" class="answer options">M</label><br> <br>

  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="dat">
  <label for="cat" class="answer options">D</label><br> <br>

  <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

```js
$('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 
  if ($('#myForm input[name="answer"]:checked').val() === 'cat') {
    window.alert("Correct");
  } else {
    window.alert("try again");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a multitude problems.

- To use the jQuery `$` function you must load the jQuery library. You can get it from [its website](https://jquery.com/)
- The selector `radio` does not look up an element by its ID, it looks up all `<radio>` elements… which don't exist in your document or in HTML. To look up an element by its ID you need `$('#The_ID')`
- `attr(...)` fetches the value of the attribute with the name passed from the selected element. None of your elements have `d="something"`.
- You are running this code while the document loads, which is before the user will have had a chance to pick an option. You need to listen for the submit event (and then stop the form from submitting to the server)
- Your checkboxes all have different names, so multiple of them can be selected at once
- The `for` attribute of a `<label>` has to match the **id** of the input it is associated with.

Assuming your goal is:

- WHEN the user clicks the submit button
- FIND which checkbox they checked
- CHECK if they picked option `dat` (although that is the wrong answer)

Then you need something along the lines of:

```js
$('form').on('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const choice = $('input[name="missing"]:checked').val();
  if (choice === 'dat') {
    alert("Correct");
  } else {
    alert("try again");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <p class="question">What is the missing letter?</p>
  <!-- image of cat -->
  <p class="cat">_ A T</p>
  <input type="radio" id="c" name="missing" value="cat">
  <label for="c" class="answer options">C</label><br><br>

  <input type="radio" id="m" name="missing" value="mat">
  <label for="m" class="answer options">M</label><br> <br>

  <input type="radio" id="d" name="missing" value="dat">
  <label for="d" class="answer options">D</label><br> <br>

  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="missingletter.css">
    <title>Missing letter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="images"></div>
    <div class="wordToGuess"></div>
    <form action="" id="theform">
        <p class="question">What is the missing letter?</p>
        <!-- image of cat -->
        <p class="cat">_ A T</p>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="cat">
        <label for="cat" class="answer options">C</label><br><br>

        <input type="radio" name="option" value="mat">
        <label for="cat" class="answer options">M</label><br> <br>

        <input type="radio" name="option" value="dat">
        <label for="cat" class="answer options">D</label><br> <br>

        <button type="submit" id="btn">Submit</button>


    </form>

    <script>
        const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
        btn.onclick = function(){
            const options = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="option"]');
            let selectedValue;
            for (const option of options) {
                if (option.checked) {
                    selectedValue = option.value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(selectedValue == 'cat'){
                alert('Correct.')
            }else{
                alert('Try Again.')
            }
            
        };
    </script>
    <div class="letters">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```